# Qt, C++ захват ссылки в асинхронной лямбде

Tags: c++, qt

Насколько безопасно так делать?

```
void wait() const
{
    QEventLoop waiter;

    QTimer timer;

    auto quiter = [&]()
    {
        waiter.quit();
    };

    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, quiter);
    timer.start(1000);
    waiter.exec();
}
```

Ссылки в лямбде не протухнут на момент сработки таймера?
PS: вместо таймера можно подставить любой асинхронный объект, который триггернет лямбду.

Comment: Пока waiter.exec() не завершит свою работу - безопасно

Comment: *"Ссылки в лямбде не протухнут на момент сработки таймера"* - следить за непротуханием ссылок в С++ - обязанность программиста.

Comment: смущает то, что лямбда quiter() вызовется в другой нитке, при асинхронном ее вызове, как поведет себя стек wait()  в этом случае?

Comment: @IvanSodorenko, где ты здесь увидел другую нитку?

Comment: В первоначальном вопросе, когда лямбду триггернет асинхронный объект, допустим какой нибудь сокет в отдельном потоке.

Comment: @IvanSodorenko, во-первых, не засовывай сокет в отдельный поток (если не абсолютно уверен, что это необходимо), во-вторых, для объектов из разных потоков сигнал по-умолчанию будет работать как `QueuedConnection` и он будет исполняться в контексте того потока, который передан принимающим объектом т.е. `this`... так что тут тоже всё в порядке... ну и в-третьих, конечно, в примере в вопросе лямбда лишняя..

Comment: @Fat-Zer хорошо, не сокет, просто долгая асинхронная операция.
контекст this это тоже понятно, но что будет с локальной QEventLoop waiter; через 1-2 секунды асинхронного ожидания.
Можно придумать не Qt пример, на std::thread с callback лямбдами, сути вопроса это не поменяет.

Comment: см. «во-вторых» выше^

Comment: и ещё забы дописать: ни кто вообще не обещает корректную работу `QObject`'ов внутри `std::thread`... не говоря уж о сигналах...